# Does Cassandra works with IBM JVM

Tags: cassandra, j9

Can I install and start Cassandra  into a x-linux OS with a IBM SDK for Java?
Will that work?  Any specific version? 2.1, 2.0 that will work ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it should work. The only issue is in the Cassandra-env.sh, you need to comment out some checking.

Comment: Yes, need to comment out the checking of jdk.                                        #if [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.8" ] && [ "$JVM_PATCH_VERSION" \< "25" ] ; then
#    echo "Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7u25 or later."
#    exit 1;
#fi

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should.  According to the [Apache Cassandra project site](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted):

> Cassandra requires the most stable version of Java 7 or 8 you can deploy, preferably the Oracle/Sun JVM. Cassandra also runs on OpenJDK **and the IBM JVM**.

As far as I can tell, it doesn't indicate that only specific versions of Cassandra work with the IBM JVM.  That being said, the documentation on the DataStax site specically mentions the Oracle JVM in the [installation steps](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installJreDeb.html).  It is the recommeded JVM to use.

I can't remember for sure, but I have heard of people running into issues that were traced back to the OpenJDK.  I don't recall anything specific to the IBM JVM.  So it might work, but it isn't supported and you might leave yourself open to some unforeseen errors.

Comment: yes, can start cassandra 2.1 with IBM JDK 1.7. Thanks for your prompt reply.